# Prove that $(0,1)\times(0,1) \subset R^2$ is an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I know how to prove that $(0,1) \subset R$ is an open set. But I can't apply the same logic to $R^2$.
Here's what I tried:

- Take $x = (x_1,x_2)$ an arbitrary element from $(0,1)\times(0,1)$
- Let $\epsilon = \min\{1 - x_1, x_1, 1 - x_2,x_2\}$
- Take $y \in B_\epsilon(x)$, arbtitrary.

Now I need to prove that $y \in (0,1)\times(0,1)$

All I can use is $\displaystyle \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2} < \epsilon$, and I need to show that $0 < y_1 < 1$ and $0 < y_2 < 1$

I saw that question: [Show that $(a,b)\times (c,d)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidian metric.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2655632/show-that-a-b-times-c-d-is-an-open-set-in-mathbbr2-with-the-euclidia) but it doesn't help.

Comment: For cartesian products, try to prove that $\text{int}(A\times B)=\text{int}A\times\text{int}B$ and $\overline{A\times B}=\overline{A}\times\overline{B}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \epsilon=\frac{1}{2} \min\{1 - x_1, x_1, 1 - x_2,x_2\}$.

Suppose $\displaystyle \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2} < \varepsilon$, then $|x_1 - y_1|< \varepsilon$ and we can write this as
$$0<x_1-\varepsilon <y_1<x_1+\varepsilon <1.$$
Same for $y_2$.

Comment: Maybe a little late, but I don't understand why $\displaystyle \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2} < \varepsilon$, then $|x_1 - y_1|< \varepsilon$, can you help me?

Comment: $|x_1 - y_1|  = \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2}\leqslant  \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2}$

Comment: Ohhh, thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**  One approach would be to note that $\Bbb R^2$ has the *product topology*.  In particular, if you cross open sets, you get an open set.

Comment: to elaborate a little more on this idea, for any open ball $B(0,\epsilon)$, pick any $x \in B(0,\epsilon)$ and try to fit an open box $(a,b) \times (c,d) \subset B(0,\epsilon)$ which contains $x$; conversely, for any open box in $(a,b) \times (c,d)$, pick $x$ in the box and try to find a ball $B \ni x$ that is contained in $(a,b) \times (c,d)$.